# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in browserify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, browserify, client-side

I need to use this [ng-if-bootstrap-grid](https://github.com/xErik/ng-if-bootstrap-grid) package in my project, Though in order to get the package working I need to install [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) by following command:
`npm install -g browserify`

my code to use it is:

`var ng =require('ng-if-bootstrap-grid').name;
angular.module('myApp',ng);`

But I still get this error:
**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing browserify package globally is not enough you should browserify all packages you want to use using `require()`. Follow steps below to achive your goal:

1) `browserify -r ng-if-bootstrap-grid > bundle.js`

2) include generated `boundle.js` in your html file before other `script` files

3) use your code:

```
var ng =require('ng-if-bootstrap-grid').name;
angular.module('myApp',ng);
```

Your final code should look like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    ...
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
        var ng =require('ng-if-bootstrap-grid').name;
        angular.module('myApp',ng);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: you can browserify multiple packages using command below:

```
browserify -r package1 -r package2 -r package3 > bundle.js
```